# What are the prepositions of "hear"?

Tags: prepositions

I wrote:

> You can’t hear such slogans **from** the current government of Rohani, nor **from** the reformists leading by Khatami.

I didn't see the preposition for "hear" pointing to the source of something you hear. Is it "from"? is it common to use it?

Comment: "Hear from" is fine usage.  However, your conjunction introducing the second part of the sentence should be **nor** rather than **neither**.

Comment: Here you are: One doesn't hear slogans such as these coming from the current Rohani government or reformists lead by Khatami.

Comment: I believe you mean "prepositions", not "propositions".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is quite common.

> Is there any noise **from** the fan belt?

Paraphrase: is the fan belt producing any sound? Is it squeaking or squealing?

> You've been sitting quietly in the back of the classroom. We haven't heard a peep from you, Ahmad.  What do you think about this new law?
>
> We have heard such empty rhetoric from the mayor on many occasions. When will he actually take some action to fix the broken streetlamps in our neighborhood?